# Citing a non-previewable .nbib file on Overleaf

Tags: citing, natbib, overleaf

I need to cite a research article I obtained from PubMed and I decided to try and use the .nbib download option for citation. From what I understand by browsing on this forum, you cite a .nbib file by having the following in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```

then have `\cite{key}` where I want to put down a citation identifier in the middle of my article, the *key* being something you could find if you are able to preview a .nbib file.
So in the case that I am not able to figure out what *key* is, what should I do?
(I have also noticed that the Overleaf tutorial for [Bibliography management with Natbib](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_natbib) mentions the usage .bib files, rather than .nbib files, perhaps that's something to do with the problem?_

Comment: The nbib format is a pub-med specific format that cannot be used with bibtex, natbib, or biblatex. There are some online tools that may be able to convert the nbib to a bib file for you (if you google .nbib to .bib conversion, you may find these). Once you have a .bib file that contains the entry, you'll need to upload that to your Overleaf project, and also reference it using the \bibliography{myBibFile} command.

Comment: Note also (1) it is not correct that this is how you cite an .nbib file, (2) the problem has nothing to do with not being able to preview the file on Overleaf. There maybe some confusion between "nbib" and "natbib" here.

Comment: I can't remember what PubMed offers, but if sites don't offer `.bib` for download, `.ris` is often available and easy to convert. (At least, it's easy on Linux. At worst, it's a plain text file, so viewing it is not a problem.)

Comment: Better try JabRef. It can  download the reference with the PMID code, or the DOI, or searching in PubMed without open the browser, and the reference will will saved in the  bibtex (.bib) format directly that as said, is what you really need.